# Can't pass parameter to reverse router in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

I have defined a route like this:

```
GET /login controllers.Login.showForm(continue: Option[String] = None)
```

Login.showForm is this:

```
def showForm(continue: Option[String] = None) = Action { implicit request =>
    val nextPage = continue match {
      case None => routes.CtrlIndex.index().absoluteURL().toString()
      case Some(page) => page
    }
    Ok(views.html.login(nextPage))
  }
```

Now, using action composition I made an authenticated action that performs this when the user is not authenticated:

```
val continue =
  if (request.method == "GET") request.uri 
  else routes.CtrlIndex.index().absoluteURL().toString() // This is not code duplication for reasons that are out of the scope of this question.
Redirect(routes.Login.showForm(Some(continue)))
```

This fails to compile with this message:

```
too many arguments for method showForm: ()play.api.mvc.Call
[error] Redirect(routes.Login.showForm(Some(continue)))
```

Changing the route definition makes it work:

```
GET /login controllers.Login.showForm(continue: Option[String])
```

But then when I use the javascript reverse router, it generates the following error in the generated javascript:

```
SyntaxError: missing formal parameter
function(continue) {
---------^
```

I have tried all combination of the definition of the function signatures but when the javascript works, the other stops working or the other way around. How can I use

- Optional parameter on /login
- Use the reverse javascript router
- Redirect to /login with the "continue" parameter
- I would also like to change `request.uri` for something that returns an absolute path.

Thanks in advance

PS. If you see something in Spanish, let me know and I'll fix it, the code is originally in Spanish; I may have missed something even after I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely cause is that "continue" is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0779sbks%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) in javascript

Play's javascript reverse router constructs a given route using the controller path and method argument(s) specified in the routes file; in your case, "continue" may be tripping up the js parser, much like a method named "delete", which works fine server-side but will blow up in the client-side reverse router.

This may be a non-issue for newer browsers, but have been bitten by "delete" method name on older versions of Internet Explorer (that we are required to support).

Comment: Oh man, I feel like an idiot. On the bright side, I guess this won't bite me again. Thanks!